# How to retrive duplicate records in talend integration

Tags: integration, talend

I want to retrieve duplicate records using talend integration open studio
 
. **Example Records are:**

```
id  name
1   suresh
2   ramesh
3   nagesh
4   suresh
```

Could anyone please answer for above queston
**expected results are:**

```
id  name
1   suresh
4   suresh
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: Use the tUniqueRow component.  The schema should define only the field "name"  as part of the unique key. Then, from the tUniqueRow component out the "Duplicates" output and send that to a tLowRow or some other component for further processing.

There is a good example in Talend's online [documentation](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide521EN/6.6+tUniqRow)

Comment: I want to retrieve what ever records having duplicate records.By using you idea i am getting only one records i.e..,                                                                  1  suresh.                                                                                                   but i want 2 records i.e..,                                                                                                 1  suresh                                                                                                     4 suresh

Answer (score 3):

Until tUniqueRow duplicates doesn't work properly you can use a trick.
I split your task into two steps.

Firstly you need to get names that are duplicated. You can do this by using tAggregateRow component. Group by name, and count number of ids. Then after filter count>1 you can save these results in tHashOutput. tHashOutput saves results in memory and it is possible to use them later.

[image: duplicates_1st_step]

In second step read your data again and using tMap match them with results saved in HashOutput. If you use Join Model = Inner Join them in tMap output you'll get only these names that exists in saved duplicates.

[image: duplicates_2nd_step]

Answer (score 1):

Finally i have found the duplicate records.I have used bellow rules.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nqFV.png)

first need to map deliminator file to tuniqrow after that map duplicate rows from tuniqrow to taggretaterow.in taggregaterow grouping the id.after that map to the tmap.
in tmap i have joined id==id and make sure as inner join.

```
Example Join condition
```

[image: capture]